# Where can I find documentation for WSPBuilder 1.03?

Tags: wspbuilder

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to get WSPBuilder working. The codeplex project is located here :http://www.codeplex.com/wspbuilder/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=16820

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this run through here

http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2009/04/08/wspbuilder-walkthrough-of-the-visual-studio-add-in.aspx